# NSDecimal number multiplication

Tags: ios, swift, multiplication, nsdecimalnumber

I am trying to do some calculations of text fields I got it to work using Doubles:

```
let firstValue = Double(miles.text!)
    let secondValue = Double(payPerMile.text!)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

    let result = Double(firstValue! * secondValue!) as NSNumber
    grossPay.text = "\(formatter.string(from: result)!)"
```

While doing more research on the subject I was informed that using Doubles is not the best route to go so I am trying to use NSDecimalNumber instead.

My problem is I can't figure out how to get it to work when switching over.

```
@IBAction func miles(_ sender: Any) {

    let firstValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: miles.text)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

    miles.text = "\(formatter.string(from: firstValue as NSNumber)!)"

}

@IBAction func payPerMile(_ sender: Any) {

    let firstValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: payPerMile.text)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

    payPerMile.text = "\(formatter.string(from: firstValue as NSNumber)!)"

}

@IBAction func grossPay(_ sender: Any) {

    let firstValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: miles.text!)
    let secondValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: payPerMile.text!)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

    let result = (firstValue as Decimal) * (secondValue as Decimal) as NSDecimalNumber
    grossPay.text = "\(formatter.string(from: result)!)"
```

just gives me the result of NaN

miles.text is formatted to .decimal
payPerMile.text is formatted to .currency

I am not sure if that could be part of my problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

If `payPerMile` is formatted as .currency, then it probably contains a currency-character. You cannot simply create an `NSDecimalNumber` from such a string.

Your second line gives you a `NaN` for `secondValue`.

What you can do, is use an `NumberFormatter` to get the `NSNumber` from the string.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
let payPerMileNumber = formatter.number(from: "$34.75") // NSNumber with 34.75
```

Comment: Can you show an actual example of the `miles` and `payPerMile` text?

Comment: I added the code for miles and payPerMile.... Hope that is what you needed.